# WSO2 - cookie on second call in Service Proxy

Tags: cookies, service, proxy, wso2, esb

I need to make proxy service in wso2 esb, that would be redirect requests to external wsdl service with pre send auth request to separate operation. 
I make sequence like this:

```
clone
   payloadFactory (auth xml request)
   call (auth operation)
   property (value=get-property('transport', 'Set-Cookie'), name=ExtCookie scope=operation)
property (value=get-property('operation', 'ExtCookie') name=Cookie)
Send (target operation)
```

When I make first call to this proxy service - It's work fine. But on second call I see in tcpdump that there is Cookie HTTP Header in the clone request.

I try add "property remove" with different scope(transport, operation, Synapse, default, axis2, axis2-client), but no one work. Cookie-Header wasn't removed. I need remove it for correct work with ext service.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following properties.

`<property name="EXCESS_TRANSPORT_HEADERS" scope="axis2" action="remove"/>
<property name="Set-Cookie" scope="transport" action="remove"/>`

Comment: I think, that there is cookie header cached in "endpoint", and it's adding to request on send to "endpont"